# How to move arr.begin() pointer to N time in the vector by simple adding not by looping

Tags: c++, gcc

I want to move my posistion pointer to N block front in the vector

let assume
`auto pos = arr.begin()`
// I want to move my pos to N block front

---

---

I have use arr.begin() and then add N to jump to N size block but can I do it. Is it possible to jump N space directly or Is there any neat way to do it.

`auto pos = arr.begin() + N;`

### or

```
for(int i=0;i\<N;i++){
poi++;
}
```

Comment: For vector or array iterators you can just add to it. For more generic handling of all different kind of iterators use [`std::advance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) or [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next).